# Console application keeps losing it's connection to class library

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application, class-library

I have tried this with an existing console application and a brand new console application.  I include the class library project in the console application.  It works fine until I build it, then I get an error asking if I'm missing a reference.  This is my first console application, is there something I don't know about console applications and class libraries?

Comment: How *exactly* are you including a reference to the class library? As a project reference, or are you browsing to the DLL? There's nothing special about console apps when it comes to references.

Comment: Have you added the reference? It's not clear from the question what the exact steps you're taking to reference the class library are.

Comment: I think, his purpose of missing references is that his project didn't start when he hit the F5.

Comment: Mising a reference to _which_ DLL, and can you see that DLL in the references (pseudo-)folder?

Comment: I added the class library project to the solution.  I set the console project as the startup project.  I added the reference by selecting "Add Reference" on the console application, then selecting the class library project from the projects tab.

I'm using this same class library in an ASP.Net MVC application.  It works fine when adding it to that project, just not the console application

Comment: Are you using the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile?

Comment: Yes, both are set to .Net Framework 4

Comment: @Johra: And now read and respond to the "Client Profile" part.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. At the point when I try to build the console app the build fails because it no longer has the reference; so all classes in the reference are unknown. I got no help here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the console application to Startup Project so when you hit the F5, your console application will be executed.

Comment: No. Trying to run a DLL does _not_ give a message about missing references.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. At the point when I try to build the console app the build fails because it no longer has the reference; so all classes inside the reference are unknown to it.

To fix the problem, I changed the project to target ".NET Framework 4" rather than ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding class library namespace to console application?

```
using <library class namespace name>;
```

It worked for me!